keeping key as a column after groupby
i want the groupby key to be a column, but instead it is returned as one space below the others.
    def function(list, A, B, C)
        A_dict = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list, A)), columns = ['site', 'A'])
        B_dict = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list, B)), columns = ['site', 'B'])
        C_dict = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(list, C)), columns = ['site', 'C'])
        Adf = A_dict.groupby('site').sum()
        Bdf = B_dict.groupby('site').sum()
        Cdf = C_dict.groupby('site').sum()
        dataframes = [Adf, Bdf, Cdf]
        mergedf = reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['site'],
                     how='outer'), dataframes).fillna('void')
        return mergedf 

list = [X, Y, Z, X, X, X, Y]
A =.   [1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 1]
B =    [2, 4, 5, 0, 2, 0, 0]
C =    [4, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0]


'list' is a list made from rows in the 'site' column of a dataframe and A, B, and C are lists made from rows of other columns in the dataframe
the return looks like this:
Output:




A
B
C




site





X
3
4
7


Y
1
4
4


Z
3
5
3



but i need 'site' to be here:



site
A
B
C



Any ideas?
